# Email Form and sendmail.php

Tags: php, html

I've set up a form and coded the php for it, and when I press submit I get an email as expected, except it keeps missing off whatever was in the name field and I cant figure out why.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="feedback_ajax_form">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="yourname" id="name_f" value="Name*" class="required" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Name*') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name*';}">
  <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email_f" value="Email*" class="required" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email*') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email*';}">
  <textarea name="message" id="message_f" class="required"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="send_f">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$to = "test@exampleemail.com";
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "You have a message.";

$fields = array();
$fields{"name"} = "name";
$fields{"email"} = "email";
$fields{"phone"} = "phone";
$fields{"message"} = "message";

$body = "New Message recievedt:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

This is what I will usually receive in an email:

```
name:
email: example@example.com
phone: 01234 987654
message: Lorem Ipsum
```

If anybody could help this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`$_REQUEST['name']` should be `$_REQUEST['yourname']`.

Comment: @OP, to add on to this, remember that your $_REQUEST variables are the same as the names in the form, though I'm sure this was just an accident ;)

Comment: Thank you, I've just reused some code I had from another site and not realized.

Answer (score 2):

```
$to = "test@exampleemail.com";
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['yourname'];
$headers = "From: $from";
$subject = "You have a message.";

$fields = array();
$fields{"name"} = "name";
$fields{"email"} = "email";
$fields{"phone"} = "phone";
$fields{"message"} = "message";

$body = "New Message recievedt:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```